# Layout weight not properly set in dynamically added radio button

Tags: android, user-interface, dynamic, radio-button

In my application i have added radio button dynamically, successfully i can add and get the values my problem is UI, its not aligned properly, layout weight dint make any change in my UI

check it out my coding

Have Text View and Radion Button

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                mainparams.setMargins(0, 8, 0, 0);
```

My Dynamic Textview

```
    LinearLayout li = new LinearLayout(Appointmentdetails.this);
    li.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    li.setLayoutParams(mainparams);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainparams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mainparams1.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);

    mainparams1.weight = 1f;
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setTextSize(18);
    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    tv.setTypeface(MyriadPro);
    tv.setLayoutParams(mainparams1);
    tv.setText(Alldata.question.get(i).getgQuestion());
    tv.setSingleLine();
    tv.setPadding(25, 10, 0, 0);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#009099"));
    tv.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(10);
    tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    tv.setSelected(true);
```

My dynamic Radio button

```
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(Appointmentdetails.this);

                // rg.setLayoutParams(lparams1);

                gAnswerList.add("Select vlaue");
                for (int j = 0; j < helptext.split(Expressions).length; j++) {
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    params.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
                    // Edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams1);
                    params.weight = 1.6f;
                    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(Appointmentdetails.this);
                    rb.setText(helptext.split(Expressions)[j].toString());
                    rb.setId(j);
                    rb.setLayoutParams(params);
                    rg.addView(rb);

                }


                li.addView(tv);
                li.addView(rg);
                mQuestionLayout.addView(li);
```

My Curent Output
[image]

My radio button need to align as like edittext, kindly help me to get the proper solution,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: try giving LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT -> 0   for your Radio Group params.

Comment: Have tried but no luck, if i give 0 then radio button not showing.

Comment: you need to give layout weight for rg (Radio group) not for rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//you need to set the layout params to the Radio group also

the same `mainparams1` also you can re-use for `RadioGroup`

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainparams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

rg.setLayoutParams(mainparams1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not specified Weightsum

```
    li.setWeightSum(weightSum);
```

where weightSum = total weight of all the child views

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i got solution by adding layout params to radio group instead of radio button.